# why in Nautilus the folder doesn't open up when I drag files to the folders in the left panel?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, drag-and-drop

when I drag files to the left pane in Nautilus I'm expecting that when I'm over that folder "bookmark" to spring-open up so that I could eventually place the file in a sub-folder... but it's not working!
Is it a design flaw of the drag'n'drop or am I missing something?
Many thanks

Comment: It doesn't work that way, why would you expect something like this?

Comment: from years ago, using Mac OS. Listen, lets say you want to drag a file into a subfolder of Movies, and Movies is in the bookmark.. wouldn't you naturally drag it in movies bookmark in the side pan and expect that before dropping it you could eventually access the subfolders in there? I think it's just common sense :)

Comment: Well, it is easy to claim what you are used to in common sense. After all, it does make more sense, because you are used to it. That said, Ubuntu is not a clone of other OSs, and it should not seem unreasonable for you to slightly adjust your own expectations.

Comment: forget what I said regarding mac os (last time I used it was 8 years ago).. people move files across folders, and sometimes in subfolders as well! this is not common sense but what everyday people do I guess :)))

Comment: @DK Bose, I just deleted the other question! sorry

Comment: Then you need to file a feature request with some file manager hoping they'll see you point of view.Asking here won't help, I'm afraid.

Comment: I just thought I was missing something or doing something wrong, couldn't believe that feature was missing! :) Thanks all for joining the discussion

Comment: In Thunar this works if the side pane view is switched to `Tree`, it doesn't if switched to `Shortcuts`. I'm not that familiar with Nautilus though so I can't tell you if it is somehow similar.

Answer (score 0):

"Doesn't work that way.."? In Ubuntu 12.04 thru 16.04 the ability to click, drag, and drop files from one folder to another WORKED. This ability was lost when upgrading to 18.04 (Gnome shell using Waland). If you are using 18.04 you can no longer move files in Nautilus using drag and drop. See the old,but still active, bug: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=696321

If you want to restore drag and drop go to this workaround ["switch between Wayland and X11"](https://www.fosslinux.com/2544/how-to-switch-between-wayland-and-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10.htm/). Until the bug is fixed, there seems to be no other way. I would also suggest installing Gnome Tweaks before switching. The desktop WILL be different and you will need Tweaks to re-adjust.